# Sutta on which Buddha states the gravity of merits

Tags: theravada, reference-request, sutras, merit

What is the sutta where Buddha says about the order of merits as in for example "Observing the 5 precepts gives more merit than offering alms" and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for **Velāma Sutta** (AN 9:20). Here's  Ṭhānissaro Bhikkhu's translation: https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/AN/AN9_20.html

Answer (score 0):

> What is the sutta where Buddha says about the order of merits as in for example "Observing the 5 precepts gives more merit than offering alms" and such.

The category of doing merits by itself doesn't decide the weight of the merit, instead it's the quality/purity/sincerity of one's body/speech/and mind while doing it that'll determine the kammic weight:

> This was said by the Blessed One, said by the Arahant, so I have heard: "There are these three grounds for meritorious activity. Which three? The ground for meritorious activity made of giving, the ground for meritorious activity made of virtue, and the ground for meritorious activity made of development [meditation]. These are the three grounds for meritorious activity." ~~ [Iti 60](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/iti/iti.3.050-099.than.html#iti-060) ~~

Comment: You didn't answer the question.

Comment: @KumāraBhikkhu Bhante, feel free to participate more and enlighten us lay folks. We lay folks still have day jobs and much lay life responsibilities, which prevent us from dedicating time and resources to Dhamma study and practice, unlike you full-time professional monastics.